# Passing data from http api to bigquery using google cloud function python

Tags: python, json, pandas, google-bigquery

I am new to google cloud function and python but I managed to check online and write the below code in the main.py file but unable to get the data into bigquery

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
from pandas.io import gbq
import pandas_gbq
import gcsfs


def validate_http(request):
  request_json = request.get_json()
  
  if request.args:
    get_api_data()
    return f'Data pull complete'
  
  elif request_json:
    get_api_data()
    return f'Data pull complete'
  
  else:
    get_api_data()
    return f'Data pull complete'


def get_api_data():
  
  import requests

  import pprint

  headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', }

  data = f'client_id={my_client_id}&client_secret={my_client_secret}&grant_type=client_credentials&scope={my_scope}'


  response = requests.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/4fa9c138-d3e7-4bc3-8bab-a74bde6b7584/oauth2/v2.0/token', headers=headers, data=data)

  json_response = response.json()

  access_token = json_response["access_token"]

  import requests
  from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

  url = "my_api_url"

  headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
  headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
  headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {access_token}"


  resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

  import json

  new_json_response = resp.json()
  new_json_response2 = new_json_response["value"]

  j_data = json.dumps(new_json_response2)
  input_data = j_data
  data = json.loads(input_data)
  result = [json.dumps(record) for record in data]
  ndjson = "\n".join(result)
  df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(ndjson)
  

  bq_load('TABLE_NAME', df)

  
def bq_load(key, value):
  
  project_name = 'PROJECT_ID'
  dataset_name = 'DATASET_NAME'
  table_name = key
  
  value.to_gbq(destination_table='{}.{}'.format(dataset_name, table_name), project_id=project_name, if_exists='replace')
```

Can anyone help with what the issue is or if there is another way to get my json data to bigquery with python and google cloud function?

I have created a table in bigquery with the dataframe as well as per the screenshot below
[panda_dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q930z.png)

Error message is below
[error message in logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb208.png)

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: Did you try replacing the url and big query variables with the actual values? Just some quick notes: 1. you may not need to import libraries twice; 2. make sure to declare within scope variables with unique names.

Comment: @Clegane I have added the screenshot of the error message in the logs

Comment: @Digelim I replaced the url and bq variables. The python code is pulling the json data properly but not able to push it through to bigquery

Comment: You have an invalid column name (**0**), change it. Bigquery does not accept a column that starts with a number.