# Python API call to BigQuery using cloud functions

Tags: python, pandas, function, google-bigquery, cloud

I'm trying to build my first cloud function. Its a function that should get data from API, transform to DF and push to bigquery. I've set the cloud function up with a http trigger using validate_http as entry point. The problem is that it states the function is working but it doesnt actually write anything. Its a similiar problem as the problem discussed here: [Passing data from http api to bigquery using google cloud function python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74093547/passing-data-from-http-api-to-bigquery-using-google-cloud-function-python/75282597?noredirect=1#comment132841983_75282597)

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
from pandas.io import gbq
import pandas_gbq
import gcsfs



#function 1: Responding and validating any HTTP request

def validate_http(request):
  request.json = request.get_json()
  
  if request.args:
    get_api_data()
    return f'Data pull complete'
  
  elif request_json:
    get_api_data()
    return f'Data pull complete'
  
  else:
    get_api_data()
    return f'Data pull complete'

#function 2: Get data and transform

def get_api_data():

    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    import json

    #Setting up variables with tokens
    base_url = "https://"
    token= "&token="
    token2= "&token="
    fields = "&fields=date,id,shippingAddress,items"
    date_filter = "&filter=date in '2022-01-22'"
    data_limit = "&limit=99999999"

    #Performing API call on request with variables
    def main_requests(base_url,token,fields,date_filter,data_limit):
        req = requests.get(base_url + token + fields +date_filter + data_limit)
        return req.json()

        #Making API Call and storing in data
    data = main_requests(base_url,token,fields,date_filter,data_limit)

    #transforming the data
    df = pd.json_normalize(data['orders']).explode('items').reset_index(drop=True)
    items = df['items'].agg(pd.Series)[['id','itemNumber','colorNumber', 'amount', 'size','quantity', 'quantityReturned']]
    df = df.drop(columns=[ 'items', 'shippingAddress.id', 'shippingAddress.housenumber', 'shippingAddress.housenumberExtension', 'shippingAddress.address2','shippingAddress.name','shippingAddress.companyName','shippingAddress.street', 'shippingAddress.postalcode', 'shippingAddress.city', 'shippingAddress.county', 'shippingAddress.countryId', 'shippingAddress.email', 'shippingAddress.phone'])
    df = df.rename(columns=
         {'date' : 'Date',
          'shippingAddress.countryIso' : 'Country',
          'id' : 'order_id'})

    df = pd.concat([df, items], axis=1, join='inner')      
  
  #Push data function
    bq_load('Return_data_api', df)
 

#function 3: Convert to bigquery table
  
def bq_load(key, value):
  
  project_name = '375215'
  dataset_name = 'Returns'
  table_name = key
  
  value.to_gbq(destination_table='{}.{}'.format(dataset_name, table_name), project_id=project_name, if_exists='replace')
```

The problem is that the script doesnt write to bigquery and doesnt return any error. I know that the get_api_data() function is working since I tested it locally and does seem to be able to write to BigQuery. Using cloud functions I cant seem to trigger this function and make it write data to bigquery.

Comment: `request_json` is not defined, so the code will break if it hits the `elif` condition containing it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried using request.json. The script loads but unfortunately still gives the following error: TypeError: get_api_data() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: i refer to line 19 of the code. the variable `request_json` is not defined.  did you mean `request.json` ??   note the difference `-` and `.` separating the words.

Comment: yes, sorry for not being specific enough. I replaced request_json with request.json as a potential fix, but it unfortunately didnt work. Do you have any other ideas how I could try to troubleshoot/fix this?

Comment: yes,  you need to change the class `JsonArrayStore` to store the data as csv (just comma separated values, without any brackets or quotes, to be a valid csv)....  so when i tested with 3 words the contents are `["hello", "world", "moon"]`, but should be just `hello, world, moon`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with the code that would set you right.

- you have list data, so store as a csv file (in preference to json).

this would mean updating (and probably renaming) the `JsonArrayStore` class and its methods to work with CSV.

Once you have completed the above and written well formed csv, you can proceed to this:

- reading the `csv` in the `del_btn` method would then look like this:

```py
import python

class ToDoGUI(tk.Tk):
    ...
    # methods
    ...

    def del_btn(self):
        a = JsonArrayStore('test1.csv')
        # read to list
        with open('test1.csv') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            data = list(reader)
        
        print(data)
```

Good work, you have a lot to do, if you get stuck further please post again.